# Apply a function to two elements of a vector

Tags: r

Wow, I'm completely blind... I read the apply, lapply, etc. docs but I wasn't able to find anything.

Let's say I have a vector

```
a = c(1,4,5,23,6,3,121,412,23)
```

I want to apply a function to c(1,4), c(4,5), c(5,23), etc. Thus, the resulting vector should be of the length

```
length(a)-1
```

I assume, that is really simple. Even, I think I made it already. But thanks for any help.

The function I want to apply is basically the slope or derivative.

Thanks to the answers I have now:

```
slope = function(p){ 
  return (p[2] - p[1])
}
foo = rollapply(a, 2, slope)
```

Comment: Please specify which function. There are specialized and efficient solutions for rolling sum, mean, difference, ...

Comment: @Dason Without the nifty details on how it works, it is hardly an complete answer. I think your answer has all the exemplary characteristics, and IMHO better answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `rollapply` function from the zoo package seems to be what you want

```
> library(zoo)
> a
[1]   1   4   5  23   6   3 121 412  23
> rollapply(a, 2, sum)
[1]   5   9  28  29   9 124 533 435
```

Note that there are custom rollxxx type functions for specific operations so more detail could provide a more optimized solution.

Edit: After seeing your edit it's clear that all you want is `diff`.

```
> diff(a)
[1]    3    1   18  -17   -3  118  291 -389
```

Comment: Thanks also for the diff() function. But at other places I will need the rollapply() solution. Thanks for the good help.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want to sum the two elements (`1+4` then `4+5`, etc). You can use `mapply`:

```
mapply(sum, a[-1], head(a,-1))
#[1]   5   9  28  29   9 124 533 435
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply` functions, which generally make our life easier. Consider a random function (let's call it foo - I'll only use base-R):

```
a = c(1,4,5,23,6,3,121,412,23)
new <- as.data.frame(matrix(a, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
mapply(foo, new[, 1], new[, 2])
```

or if vectorized operations are supported by that specific function:

```
foo(new[, 1], new[, 2])
```